# Can U.S. car dealerships pull your entire credit report or just your FICO score?

Tags: united-states, credit-score, credit, credit-report, fico-score

In the U.S. can car dealerships pull your **entire** credit report, or just your score if you go into them to apply for a loan? Of all the research I've done, it sounds like its just your FICO score that they're allowed to pull, not the entire report, but I haven't found any concrete evidence to support either one.

Comment: When I bought my car a few years ago they definitely had the full report. Can they even pull "just your score"?

Comment: Remember that even when a lender/financier pulls a "full report", it isn't as complete as the report you see when you pull your own report.

Comment: What difference does it make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the credit is provided through an outside lender (basically always) then only they would have access to the full report, and through discussions with the finance rep at the dealership, they can provide details about the report (approved or not approved and why).

Answer (score 1):

When they pull your credit report you generally sign a paper giving them the right to do it. So they can pull whatever you give them permission to do.